# how to compile this Code and print the Result?

Tags: java, compilation

the following java code wont run ,i want to know the result by compiling this code please!

```
    class ParseInt{
        static void main(String [] a){
            int b=Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
            int m = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i=0; i<32; i++){
                System.out.print(( b & m >>> i )== 0 ? "0" : "X");
                //System.out.print(((b &(m >>> i))== 0)? "0" : "X");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error messages? Input values?

Answer (score 5):

Your main method needs to be public. More to the point, it needs to conform to the signature:

```
public static void main(String[] a)
```